# how to ignore recordings while showing only .mp3 songs of external storage in listview of music player app android

Tags: android, android-music-player

//code is perfect but I don't want calls or recordings to show here what should be modified..?

```
private void display() {
        final ArrayList<File> arrayList=  findsongsfromdirectory(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());

        item = new String[arrayList.size()];

        for(int i=0;i< arrayList.size();i++)
        {
         item[i]=arrayList.get(i).getName().replace(".mp3"," ").replace(".wav"," ");
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,item);
        lv_mp.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    }
    ArrayList<File> findsongsfromdirectory(File file)
    {
        ArrayList<File> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        File [] files = file.listFiles();

        if(files!=null)
        for(File singleFile : files)
        {
            if(singleFile.isDirectory() && !singleFile.isHidden())
            {
                arrayList.addAll(findsongsfromdirectory(singleFile));
            }
            else if( singleFile.getName().endsWith(".mp3") ||singleFile.getName().endsWith(".wav"))
            {

                arrayList.add(singleFile);
            }
        }



        return arrayList;
    }
```

As you can see i got all mp3 format audios including recorded calls but I only want songs of the format not recordings

[image: As you can see i got all mp3 format audios including recorded calls but I only want songs of the format not recordings]

Comment: Please improve code identation. Also explain better what you mean by call and recordings.

Comment: As you can see in the screenshot of the app the list items "9 Dec 21.52 "are personal recordings and " call@pam" are call recordings. I don't want them to be shown in music player app. what changes should I make so that i can only show music (not recordings) in app's listview :)

Answer (score 0):

One option would be using regex to match the common filenames of personal and call recordings and exclude them from the list of files you will display.

Comment: Can't use regex as recordings can be renamed when saved (if not named  then they are saved by the default names.. :)